# My Firebird electric guitar's bridge pickup is operating at a very low volume. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Tags: audio, music, guitar-amplifier

I have a Firebird electric guitar with two mini humbucker pickups.

Both pickups have been good since I got it, but suddenly the bridge pickup stopped working. The neck pickup is fully operational, but the bridge pickup is barely audible.

If I turn the amp up to 10 I get a very faint signal through the bridge pickup, but it is nowhere near a usable volume.

It does this on every amp too, so I can rule any amplifier issues out.

Does anybody know why this kay have happened, and how could I repair this?

Comment: Product repair questions are not on topic here; you should probably try to find an electric guitar forum where you'll be able to get advice from those with experience of this sort of product.

Comment: Sounds like a wire broke loose inside or something. Try taking it to a luthier, could be an easy fix for a skilled guitar repair tech.

Comment: You need to turn the amp up to 11.

Comment: The folks here don't care about your guitar   LOL   Your problem is not an engineering problem and thus isn't going to be interesting to them.   Try a different forum where the folks get off on fixing guitars such as:  https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?forums/amps-cabs-tech-corner-amplifier-cab-speakers.11/   And yes, whatever is wrong with is, is going to be a super-easy fix for somebody with a multimeter and some modicum of circuit understanding.  There are few electronic things around more basic than an electric guitar.   Maybe a flashlight....